# C# How to stop Ping in a BackGroundWorker / Stop SendAsync outside of function

Tags: c#

So i have a BW that looks like this:

```
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(1);
            e.Result = PCIsOnline((string)e.Argument);
        }
    }
```

PCIsOnline function starts Ping.Send. Everything works fine.
But in some cases i want to stop BW (or stop ping).

I've tryed this:

bw.CancelAsync(); - but that doesnt help me coz APP will never go back to bw_DoWork again to stop. So i there a way to stop ping or bw.
So i can start it again.

Btw for some reason this doesn't helping too.

```
    bw.CancelAsync();
    while (!bw.IsBusy)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
```

Coz its just loops forever. I guess its becoz i Sleep thread, but its a main thread i though that BW thread shouldn't stop. But it seems like it does. I've seen a thread where instead of sleep DoEvents was used but i'm using WPF and it doesn't have it. And i don't realy want to wait ping to finish it's job.

I've read a lot of threads about BW and how to stop but none is helpfull in my case. Coz by the time i send CancelAsync() DoWork allready passed CancellationPending check and will never return there.

PS: Fisrt time i start BW in TextBox_FocusLost even. And want to Stop and Run it again in List_SelectChanged.

**ADDED:**

```
public static bool PCIsOnline(string arg)
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

    options.DontFragment = true;

    string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    int timeout = 2;
    try
    {
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(arg, timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**ADDED2:**
As it was stated in comment before that instead of using BW is better to use SendAsync. Аnd my code now looks like this. But i still don't understand how can i stop SendAsync outside of PCIsOnline function.

```
public static void PCIsOnline(string arg)
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();

    pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);

    PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

    options.DontFragment = true;

    string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    int timeout = 2;
    pingSender.SendAsync(arg, timeout, buffer, options);
}
private static void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping canceled.");
    }

    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping failed:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
    }

    PingReply reply = e.Reply;
    HandleReply(reply);
}
```

So I'm still looking a way to interrupt BW and restart it or a way to stop PingAsync.

Comment: Probably you PCIsOnline method is doing endless work. Need to know what you got there to able to help you/

Comment: I've added PCIsOnline, but it should do no harm it was taken from MSDN Examples.

Comment: How long does it takes to finish pingSender.Send method?

Comment: It's triggered after TextBox with text like MyWor at the same time in the List there are full names of AD PC's like MyWorkingPC, MyWorkingPC2 and so on. I want to stop pinging for MyWor and start ping for MyWorkingPC2 i've selected in a list.

Comment: Ping.Send() cannot be canceled, you must use Ping.SendAsync() and cancel with Ping.SendAsyncCancel().  At which point you might well decide that you don't really need BackgroundWorker :)

Comment: So you r saying that PingAsync() is pretty same that i did with BW ? =)

Comment: Not really a solutions in my case, Send and SendAsync freeze my APP. As I mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934144/c-sharp-run-ping-on-a-backgound-after-focus-loss-ruturning-value-to-the-textbo I need ping to run on a background so I can still work with my APP

Comment: I was wrong PingAsync() doesn't freeze app i just hade some old Ping code left. But i still don't understand how to stop all PingAsync() instances outside of PCIsOnline function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't find a way to stop ping I've decided to ignore ping results if it's not the one I need ATM.
So I just added check in to **HandleReply** that sends **return** if that this ping result not longer needed.

```
private void Name_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    //No longer Using BW since Ping.SendAsync() does the job
    PCIsOnline(textBox.Text); 
}
private void Search_SelectChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox Search = sender as ListBox;
    if (Search.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        this.OldName.Text = Search.SelectedValue.ToString();
        PCIsOnline(this.OldName.Text);
    }
}
public void PCIsOnline(string arg)
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    //Sending argument to perform check later
    pingSender.PingCompleted += (sender1, args) => PingCompletedCallback(sender1, args, arg);
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

    options.DontFragment = true;
    string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    int timeout = 5;
    pbrTest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    pingSender.SendAsync(arg, timeout, buffer, options);
}
private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e, String Current)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        HandleReply(null, Current, "Cancelled");
        return;
    }

    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        HandleReply(null, Current, "Error");
        return;
    }

    PingReply reply = e.Reply;
    HandleReply(reply, Current, "");
}
private void HandleReply(PingReply reply, String PC, String msgtype = "")
{
    //Ignore old result I only need one that is in OldName textBox
    if (PC != this.OldName.Text) { return; }
    //Next you should add your result handling
    //Happens on a error
    if (reply == null)
    {
        /*do something*/
    }
    //PC is online
    else if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        /*do something*/
    }
    //PC is offline
    else
    {
        /*do something*/
    }
}
```

Not the best way to solve the problem but that's the best I can think of.

Comment: I guess I'll mark this as an answer, that's the I have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is u only send cancel to bw . But u need to send cancel to Ping (SendAsync) too.

Send cancel to Ping

```
Ping.SendAsyncCancel();
bw.CancelAsync();
```

Use SendAsync:

```
public static bool PCIsOnline(string arg)
{
Ping pingSender = new Ping();
PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

options.DontFragment = true;

string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
int timeout = 2;
try
{
    PingReply reply = pingSender.SendAsync(arg, timeout, buffer, options);
    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: When I add this Ping.SendAsyncCancel(); I get an Exception: An Object reference is required for not static field, method or property. Correct me if I'm wrong but as far as I know Ping is a class. And i shouldn't be able to use it like this. I see only one way to do the stop at the moment that is to make pingSender an object of my class. But isn't this stupid?

Comment: Call cancel on `pingSender`

Comment: pingSender does not exists outside of PCIsOnline()